# Bar/bat Mitzvah syllabus

Tags: bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

Is there a set syllabus/topics on Jewish law,  that Halacha expects a Bar Mitzvah Boy/ Bat Mitzvah girl to know by the time they are Bar/Bat Mitzvah?

Comment: Everyone is alway expected to know everything they need to not mess up. Most of us fail, but hey that's why it's Elul yet again.

Comment: Basic hilchos teffilin for a bar mitzvah boy